# Why null reference exception in SetMolePublicInstance?

Tags: moles

I get a "null reference" exception in the following line:

```
MoleRuntime.SetMolePublicInstance(stub, receiverType, objReceiver, name, null);
```

The program builds and compiles correctly. There are no complaints about any of the parameters to the method.

Here's the specification of SetMolePublicInstance, from the object browser:

```
SetMolePublicInstance(System.Delegate _stub, System.Type receiverType, object _receiver, string name, params System.Type[] parameterTypes)
```

Here are the parameter values for "Locals":

```
+ stub {Method = {System.String <StaticMethodUnitTestWithDeq>b__0()}} System.Func<string>
+ receiverType {Name = "OrigValue" FullName = "OrigValueP.OrigValue"} System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
objReceiver {OrigValueP.OrigValue} object {OrigValueP.OrigValue}
name "TestString" string
parameterTypes null object[]
```

I know that TestString() takes no parameters and returns string, so as a starter to try to get things working, I specified "null" for the final parameter to SetMolePublicInstance. As already mentioned, this compiles OK.

Here's the stack trace:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at     Microsoft.ExtendedReflection.Collections.Indexable.ConvertAllToArray[TInput,TOutput](TInput[] array, Converter`2 converter)
   at Microsoft.Moles.Framework.Moles.MoleRuntime.SetMole(Delegate _stub, Type receiverType, Object _receiver, String name, MoleBindingFlags flags, Type[] parameterTypes)
   at Microsoft.Moles.Framework.Moles.MoleRuntime.SetMolePublicInstance(Delegate _stub, Type receiverType, Object _receiver, String name, Type[] parameterTypes)
   at DeqP.Deq.Replace[T](Func`1 stub, Type receiverType, Object objReceiver, String name) in C:\0VisProjects\DecP_04\DecP\DeqC.cs:line 38
   at DeqPTest.DecCTest.StaticMethodUnitTestWithDeq() in C:\0VisProjects\DecP_04\DecPTest\DeqCTest.cs:line 28
   at Starter.Start.Main(String[] args) in C:\0VisProjects\DecP_04\Starter\Starter.cs:line 14
Press any key to continue . . .
```

To avoid the null parameter, I changed the final "null" to "parameterTypes" as in the following line:

```
MoleRuntime.SetMolePublicInstance(stub, receiverType, objReceiver, name, parameterTypes);
```

I inserted the line:

```
Type [] parameterTypes = new Type[0];
```

Using moles.runner.exe produces the desired results :)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can not check for NullReferenceException; because, it is a runtime exception.  This exception means one of the objects passed to the arguments is null, when it is expected to point to an instance.

Place a breakpoint on that line of the test project.  Running the test in debug mode will break on that line, allowing you to see which of the arguments is null.

Comment: Mike, would you consider undeleting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900775/why-does-xml-deserialize-data-to-lower-case ?   It seems to me that it was a reasonable question that took some time to research to give you a useful comment, an a useful answer.  If you would agree with that, was your intention to take the information from the community?  (Forget my request if that question was just somehow completely misunderstood rather that answered.)